# Converting year, month and day to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. datafrme:

```
     YEAR   MO   DY  name_col 
0  2016.0  1.0  5.0     0.00 
1  2016.0  1.0  6.0     0.00 
2  2016.0  1.0  7.0     0.41 
3  2016.0  1.0  8.0     0.53 
4  2016.0  1.0  9.0     2.12
```

How do I convert the YEAR, MO and DY columns representing year, month and day respectively to datetime?

```
     YEAR   MO   DY  name_col   datetime
0  2016.0  1.0  5.0     0.00 2016-01-05
1  2016.0  1.0  6.0     0.00 2016-01-06
2  2016.0  1.0  7.0     0.41 2016-01-07
3  2016.0  1.0  8.0     0.53 2016-01-08
4  2016.0  1.0  9.0     2.12 2016-01-09
```

I tried this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_met['YEAR'].astype(int), format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df_met['DY'] - 1, unit='d')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pd.to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) can assemble datetime from multiple columns if columns have "correct" names:

```
In [106]: df
Out[106]:
     YEAR   MO   DY  name_col
0  2016.0  1.0  5.0      0.00
1  2016.0  1.0  6.0      0.00
2  2016.0  1.0  7.0      0.41
3  2016.0  1.0  8.0      0.53
4  2016.0  1.0  9.0      2.12

In [107]: df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns={'MO':'MONTH', 'DY':'DAY'}).drop('name_col', 1))

In [108]: df
Out[108]:
     YEAR   MO   DY  name_col   datetime
0  2016.0  1.0  5.0      0.00 2016-01-05
1  2016.0  1.0  6.0      0.00 2016-01-06
2  2016.0  1.0  7.0      0.41 2016-01-07
3  2016.0  1.0  8.0      0.53 2016-01-08
4  2016.0  1.0  9.0      2.12 2016-01-09
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys
>   can be common abbreviations like
>
> `[‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’, ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘us’, ‘ns’]`
>
> or plurals of the same